# Hide or readonlify inherited DependencyProperty of a child WPF control at design-time

Tags: wpf, canvas, attached-properties, design-time, rendertransform

It is possible to somehow hide (from the designer property pane) a preexisting dependency property on a custom canvas' child controls, or modify their metadata, or make them read-only?

.

**Below are details on what I am trying to accomplish**:

I'm writing a WPF Canvas-like control that has custom rules to place, size and rotate it's children.

```
<my:MyCustomCanvas> 
    <Button my:Name="child control #1" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="20"/> 
    <my:SomeOtherControl my:Name="child control #2" Canvas.Left="70" Canvas.Top="80"/> 
</my:MyCustomCanvas>
```

Example #1:

HorizontalAlignmentProperty does not make any sense in a normal canvas, but its children still display it on their property panes - it is inherited all the way from FrameworkElement. This confuses people who work with my canvas since there are layout properties that look bugged because they are there but do not work.

Changing default the value for some of those inherited properties would also be nice.

.

Example #2:

To rotate child controls I need to set their RenderTransformProperty like this:

```
protected override void OnVisualChildrenChanged(DependencyObject visualAdded, DependencyObject visualRemoved)
{
    base.OnVisualChildrenChanged(visualAdded, visualRemoved);
    foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
    {
        var group = new TransformGroup();
        var rt = new RotateTransform();
        var b = new Binding() { Source = ..., Convertor = ... };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(rt, RotateTransform.AngleProperty, b);
        group.Children.Add(rt);
        child.RenderTransform = group;
    }
}
```

If anyone sets or resets RenderTranformProperty for any reason, my binding is deleted, and the only way to recover is to close and reopen the designer window/tab.

*There is also a problem where designer itself deletes my binding, but that's a topic for another question*

This all means I am required to tell everyone (and they are required to remember) to NOT touch RenderTranform inside my canvas ever - or else everything glitches out. That is a pain, so it would be nice to know how to hide RenderTransform for child controls in the designer's property pane, or forbid to change them.